# BFS in disconnected graph for checking Bipartite graph

Tags: python, graph, breadth-first-search

I was solving the problem [BUGLIFE](http://www.spoj.com/problems/BUGLIFE/) using python. I just need to do a BFS traversal in all the components of the graph, and color the nodes appropriately.
Here is the code I wrote in python, I have no idea, why I am getting WA (Wrong Answer) in this:

```python
def bfs(graph, start, visited=set()):
    queue = [start]
    A, C = set(), set()
    while queue:
        node = queue.pop(0)
        if node not in visited:
            visited.add(node)
            queue.extend(graph[node] - visited)
            # color nodes
            if node in A:
                C = C.union(graph[node])
            elif node in C:
                A = A.union(graph[node])
            else:
                A.add(node)
                C = C.union(graph[node])
        if A.intersection(C):
            return 0
    if len(visited) == len(graph):
        return 1
    else:
        for vertex in (set(graph) - visited):
            return bfs(graph, vertex, visited)

S = int(raw_input())
for s in range(1, S+1):
    B, I = map(int, raw_input().split())
    graph = {}
    for bug in range(1, B+1):
        graph.update({bug: set()})

    for interaction in range(I):
        x, y = map(int, raw_input().split())
        graph[x].add(y)
        graph[y].add(x)

    result = bfs(graph, 1)
    print('Scenario #%d:' % s)
    if result:
        print('No suspicious bugs found!')
    else:
        print('Suspicious bugs found!')
```

This is the assignment:

> Professor Hopper is researching the sexual behavior of a rare species of bugs. He assumes that they feature two different genders and that they only interact with bugs of the opposite gender. In his experiment, individual bugs and their interactions were easy to identify, because numbers were printed on their backs.
>
> Given a list of bug interactions, decide whether the experiment supports his assumption of two genders with no homosexual bugs or if it contains some bug interactions that falsify it.
>
> #### Input
>
> The first line of the input contains the number of scenarios. Each scenario starts with one line giving the number of bugs (at least one, and up to 2000) and the number of interactions (up to 1000000) separated by a single space. In the following lines, each interaction is given in the form of two distinct bug numbers separated by a single space. Bugs are numbered consecutively starting from one.
>
> #### Output
>
> The output for every scenario is a line containing “Scenario #i:”, where i is the number of the scenario starting at 1, followed by one line saying either “No suspicious bugs found!” if the experiment is consistent with his assumption about the bugs’ sexual behavior, or “Suspicious bugs found!” if Professor Hopper’s assumption is definitely wrong.
>
> #### Example
>
> Input:
>
> ```
> 2
> 3 3
> 1 2
> 2 3
> 1 3
> 4 2
> 1 2
> 3 4
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> Scenario #1:
> Suspicious bugs found!
> Scenario #2:
> No suspicious bugs found!
> ```

Comment: This may be a mutable default argument issue. Each scenario will end up using the same `visited` set, since they're all using the default value.

Comment: I am passing the new visited in each call.

Comment: Your top level code does `result = bfs(graph, 1)` once per scenario. This reuses the mutable `visted` default, which is passed on to all recursive calls. You should make the default `None`, and add a `if visited is None: visited = set()` line at the start of the function and see if that fixes your issue.